# use awk to remove lined that are a repeat of the first field

Tags: awk

I have a file with 200,000 plus lines.  The first field is the key ID.  I need to remove 2,3,4... lines that repeat the first field.  Help please!  I'm on a deadline.  I have tried many similarly answered questions and nothing has worked.

Comment: Firstly: why does your deadline require you to use `awk`, specifically? Is there some requirement that you're not mentioning? Secondly: to make sure it's clear what you want, please post some sample input and output.

Comment: pls post example! is your file sorted? do you just want to remove duplicated (col 1 based) lines?

Comment: Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it _should_ work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -nr '1{h;s/\s*(\S+).*/\1/;x;p}; 1!{x;G;/(\S+)\n\1.*/!{s/\n.*//;x;p;b};s/\n.*//;x;d}' file.txt
```

```
$cat file.txt
line1 11111
line2 22121
line1 11212
line2 22222
line1 11313
line2 22323
line1 11414
line2 22424
line1 11515
line2 22525

$sed -nr '1{h;s/\s*(\S+).*/\1/;x;p}; 1!{x;G;/(\S+)\n\1.*/!{s/\n.*//;x;p;b};s/\n.*//;x;d}' file.txt
line1 11111
line2 22121
line2 22222
line2 22323
line2 22424
line2 22525
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
print -- "
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
4" | awk '{ if (! ($1 in alreadyPrinted)) {print $1 ; alreadyPrinted[$1]=$1;}'
```

**output**

```
1
2
3
4
```

If not, please take the time to add small sample input, and show the required output based on that input. If you do some code, include that, and include the exact text of error messages that you get.

IHTH

Comment: Since the question specifically mentions the first field, perhaps it would make sense to use `$1` rather than `$0` throughout. If the file is sorted, you just need a single variable, not an array.

Comment: good idea about $1. Not clear if data is sorted. My minimalist solution is meant to help O.P. visualize what we need to really understand the problem. Thanks and good luck to all.